# How do I fix the top-level statement's error?

Tags: c#, file, toplevel-statement

**Program1.cs** Regular C# file, works perfectly.

```cs
Random numberGen = new Random();

int roll1 = 1;
int roll2 = 0;
int roll3 = 0;
int roll4 = 0;

int attempts = 0;

Console.WriteLine("Press enter to roll the dies");

while (roll1 != roll2 || roll2 != roll3 || roll3 != roll4 || roll4 != roll1)
{
    Console.ReadKey();

    roll1 = numberGen.Next(1, 7);
    roll2 = numberGen.Next(1, 7);
    roll3 = numberGen.Next(1, 7);
    roll4 = numberGen.Next(1, 7);
    Console.WriteLine("Dice 1: " + roll1 + "\nDice 2: " + roll2 + "\nDice 3: " + roll3 + "\nDice 4: " + roll4 + "\n");
    attempts++;
}

Console.WriteLine("It took " + attempts + " attempts to roll a four of a kind.");

Console.ReadKey();
```

**Program2.cs**

```cs
Console.ReadKey();
```

Under the module *Console* it pops up an error:
*Only one compilation unit can have top-level statements.* Error: CS8802

I tried in the terminal *dotnet new console --force*, but it just ended up deleting my program.

I want to run multiple C# files in the same folder without getting the
*Only one compilation unit can have top-level statements* or other similar errors.

Comment: You want to run multiple programs at the same time? Both of them read console input. How would that work?

Comment: Isn't the error message pretty clear?  You only get one file where you can dispense with the trouble of defining a class.

Comment: Does it mean i have to make a new folder for my C# files?

Comment: @Canyon a folder would make no difference. What are you actually trying to do here? You can define anything else in another file (e.g a class), but what you're effectively doing above is defining two `Main` methods / entry points. You can only have one of those, executing more than one makes no sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In dotnet 6 and newer, it is possible to use a top-level statement, which means you do not need to have a class name for the main method.

So when you have 2 cs file that does not have class and namespace, the compiler thinks you have 2 main methods.

So you can eventually do something like for Program1.cs:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1;

class Program1
{
    public static void GetRolling()
    {
        Random numberGen = new Random();

        int roll1 = 1;
        int roll2 = 0;
        int roll3 = 0;
        int roll4 = 0;

        int attempts = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to roll the dies");

        while (roll1 != roll2 || roll2 != roll3 || roll3 != roll4 || roll4 != roll1)
        {
            Console.ReadKey();

            roll1 = numberGen.Next(1, 7);
            roll2 = numberGen.Next(1, 7);
            roll3 = numberGen.Next(1, 7);
            roll4 = numberGen.Next(1, 7);
            Console.WriteLine("Dice 1: " + roll1 + "\nDice 2: " + roll2 + "\nDice 3: " + roll3 + "\nDice 4: " + roll4 + "\n");
            attempts++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("It took " + attempts + " attempts to roll a four of a kind.");
    }
}
```

and for Program2.cs something like:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1;

public class Program2
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program1.GetRolling();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Otherwise, it is like saying you have a twice (2x) `public static void Main(string[] args)` and that is not possible. Therefore you get that Error.

Comment: How do i choose which Program i want to run?

Comment: the program that contain method Main, So Main is the entry point for your program. Program is just a class,

Comment: I will change my answer to give you better picture

Comment: so now program1 contains a method with some logic, and program 2 calling a method in program1, Program 2 have the Main method that is the entry point for starting